# Error source not found is displayed when i try to include javascript in my servlet program

Tags: javascript, servlets

```
 out.print("<tr><td>Gender:</td><td><input type=radio name=gender id=male readonly=readonly> male    <input type=radio name=gender id=female readonly=readonly>female</td></tr>");
    if(empdet[i][7].equals("1"))
    {
           out.println("<script>");
           out.println("document.getElementByID(male).checked=true;");
           out.println("</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
       out.println("document.getElementByID(female).checked=true;");
       out.println("</script>");

    }
```

When the `out.println("<script>");` line is reached

> source not found

error is thrown.

Comment: are you dealing with JSPs?

Comment: No just servlet extending HTTPservlet class  need to display logged in user details that includes radio button for gender details.I should select either male or female based on logged in user

Comment: post the full stack trace

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get the full stack trace Im new to this

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to write extra script to set the checkbox selected. You can achieve it through the HTML itself

```
out.print("<tr><td>Gender:</td>");
    if(empdet[i][7].equals("1"))
    {
           out.println("<input type=radio name=gender id=male readonly=readonly checked=checked> male ");
           out.println("<td>   <input type=radio name=gender id=female readonly=readonly>female</td>");
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("<input type=radio name=gender id=male readonly=readonly > male ");
           out.println("<td>   <input type=radio name=gender id=female readonly=readonly checked=checked>female</td>");


    }
out.println("</tr>");
```

Comment: Thanks Nishad K Ahamed for help

Comment: But may I know the reason for source not found problem Cant I include javascript in the way i included it

Comment: you need to print that in a single print statement, I think this is the problem, not sure either.